# Why can't I set a value of a pointer int *x to, say, 10?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm severely misunderstanding pointers, so hopefully someone can clarify this please.

`int *x;` is a pointer to an int. `x` refers to the pointer itself, and `*x` refers to the **value** (or target) stored at x's memory location.

If I want x to point to an int, who's value is 10, why can't I do `int *x = 10;`?

I don't quite understand why when we do something like `printf("%d", *x);`, it prints out the value stored at x but we can't do `int *x = 10;`

Comment: You are initializing the address pointed to by `x` which is declared as being of type `int *`.

Comment: How would you expect `int *x; x = 10;` to work?

Comment: Initializing a variable in C requires a compatible rvalue to the to-be-initialized id. `int *x` declares a pointer-to-int. `10` is int, not pointer-to-int. If you expect otherwise you're misinformed, as those are simply the rules of the language. It may be the position and usage of the asterisk that is throwing you off; `int *x;` indicates a pointer-to-int declaration. `printf("%d", *x);` uses it as a *dereference* operator. There is a significant difference (obviously).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion has to do with the difference between an initialization and an assignment.  These are examples of initialization:

```
int a = 5;    // valid; "a" is an int which is initialized with the value 5
int *b = &a;  // valid; "b" is an int * which is initialized with the address of "a"
int *c = 10;  // invalid; "c" is an int * which is initialized with the value 10
```

While these are assignments:

```
a = 5;    // valid; "a" is assigned the value 5
b = &a;   // valid; "b" is assigned the address of "a"
*b = 10;  // valid; "b" points to "a", and the value "b" points to is set to 10
```

Note that the use of `*` differs between the two.  In an initalization `*` means that the given variable is a pointer, while `*` in an assignment (or any expression) means that the pointer is dereferenced.

Answer (score 2):

int* x -> x is a memory adress for an Integer, type (int*).

if you do *x it displays the content because * is a operand, a memory operand that shows what is stored in that memory adress, and (int*) is a type of data,a pointer to something in the memory, very different.

Hope I explained it quickly. Good coding.

Answer (score 1):

int *x means ---- x is integer pointer type.

and 10 is a integer type.

in your case, you are trying to assign an "integer" type to " integer pointer" type, which is not valid because of two different types.